# JQuery .attr not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, attr, setattribute

I'm using a :regex library (found [here](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/)) to select elements that have IDs starting with P and having at least 5 digits afterward. Then, I use .attr to add on some attributes.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('img:regex(id,P[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]+)').attr("onmouseover", "show\(this\,2\,0\)");
$('img:regex(id,P[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]+)').attr("onmouseout", "hide\(this\)");
});
```

This works in Firefox, but not Chrome. (Haven't tested IE yet.)

I tried using [0].setAttribute instead, and it works to an extent, but then for some reason it only selects the first instance of the regex.

Does anyone have a more compatible solution?

Comment: I don't usually do this, but **omg**.

Comment: Dude, are you sure there isn't an easier way to achieve what you are looking for? And by the way what you were trying to achieve?

Comment: **P[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]+** will match **P1234** too. Use **P\d{5,}**

Comment: *"...for some reason it only selects the first instance..."* Here's a clue: `[0]`.

Comment: why don't you simply use a class instead of regex ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whatever that plugin does, it looks terribly slow. I would rather recommend to select all image nodes and then filter them with jQuery [`.filter()`<sup>help</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/filter/), this has to be faster and I think it's still more readable at all. Could look like:

```
$('img').filter(function(index) {
    return this.id.charAt(0) === 'P' && !isNaN(this.id.slice(1,6));
}).hover(function() {
     $(this).show();
}, function() {
     $(this).hide();
});
```

**Demo**: http://www.jsfiddle.net/snMCM/

**Performance benchmark**: http://jsperf.com/regex-vs-jquery-filter

Comment: I have pre-defined functions 'show' and 'hide'. This seems to be calling the JQuery ones ( [1](http://api.jquery.com/show/) [2](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) ). Is there any way to call the one's I've pre-defined instead?

Comment: @user607138: well I don't know the code of those methods, but it should be no problem to call them instead of the native versions. Just replace `$(this).show()` with `show(this);` etc.

Answer (score 3):

regEx aside, you should use the jQuery `.hover()` function, not the `.attr()` function. I've incorporate the `.hover()` function as well as the regEx provided by `kirilloid`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('img:regex(id, P\d{5,})').hover(function(){
        show( $(this), 2, 0);
    }, function(){
        hide( $(this) );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can attach javascript handlers using attr, but that sounds like a very long way of doing it.
Give this a shot:

```
$('img:regex(id,P[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]+)').hover(function() {
    show(this,2,0);
},function() {
    hide(this);
});
```

Comment: why are we incorporating `click()` into things? this is a simple `.hover()`

Answer (score 0):

I know it doesn't really answer your question but...

Add a class to the elements you want to select.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `filter()` instead of the `:regex` library? This should work in all browsers. e.g.

```
var $imgs = $('img').filter(function(){return this.id.match(/^P\d\d\d\d\d/);});
$imgs.attr("onmouse.......
```

Comment: As the others also said: if you trying to emulate a HOVER, then use jQuery's hover() method.

Answer (score 0):

Try This: (Working in all browsers)

```
        $(window).load(function () {
        //your script or function

                    $("your_html_tag").attr({
                            width : "your-width",
                            height : "your-height",
                            alt: "Online Teacher"
                        });
        });
```

Rather than

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
       //your script or function

                    $("your_html_tag").attr({
                            width : "your-width",
                            height : "your-height",
                            alt: "Online Teacher"
                        });
        });
```